# Logging in via Pokemon trainer club vs Google account

Tags: pokemon-go

My son’s account was set up with trainer club. Tab did a software update overnight that logged him out. Trainer club wouldn't accept password so he selected the Google login option but it wants to create a new character.  Will he lose all his progress if we move forward? We restarted the tab but the Pokémon app is still in the midst of picking a new character and doesn't give us the  trainer account option.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you create a new account with Google, it won't erase the trainer club account.

Comment: As Patrat has said in the answers below, the PTC servers are experiencing some trouble over the past few hours. Try checking this website for the PTC login status: http://ispokemongodownornot.com Once it's stable, you should try logging back in again.

Comment: Something that I noticed that might be your problem. The usernames for PTC are case sensitive this is unlike a lot of login systems.

Answer (score 19):

Characters and progress are tied to accounts, so if your son wants to hold onto his, he should log in with the Pokemon Trainer Club as before.

If the app isn't doing this even after a restart, the best option is probably to uninstall the app and download it again from the Google Play store. This won't harm his progress.

Comment: Thank you! I considered this but was afraid to lose it and that would be a catastrophe  in my house! :)

Comment: Yeah, I get that feeling :) If you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting/upvoting it :)

Answer (score 6):

Also, pokemon servers are highly unstable at the moment.  This doesn't affect google accounts but for those logging in with a pokemon trainer club account the odds are that it's the servers.  Try again Later before giving up.

Comment: Doesn't affect Google accounts? I can't log in with my Google account pretty often.

Comment: @KRyan Just because the pokemon servers are in a worse state doesn't mean the general servers have no problems. Google accounts may not always be working but pokemon trainer club accounts apparently have it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

All the game data is stored on server side, you can log in and out with as many accounts/game progresses as you wish from the same device and everything will keep working fine. When you logged in with a google account you loaded a new (empty) profile and game progress in which nothing had been done yet. As soon as you log in with your old account again, the old game progress will be restored. This feature also allowes to keep the game progress if you buy a new device or want to play on a device of a friend.

If sometimes the login fails with a message like "Authentification failed. Please try again." repeatedly, don't panic, it's probably just the Pokemon Go servers being down again. Wait a few hours or until the next day and they'll be working again.